# getting this error "Skipping import row, required field "website" is not defined" when importing customer list in dataflow import method

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, importexport

getting this error "Skipping import row, required field "website" is not defined" when importing customer list in dataflow import method

[image: getting this error Skipping import row, required field "website" is not defined when importing customer list in dataflow import method]

Comment: I think you are trying to import data with multiple website and you have not created that website in admin

Comment: no, i am imported for sigle site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be due to many reasons:

- **`Empty column value`** for few rows
- If **`delimiter symbol is incorrect`**, your file data won’t be parsed properly and you might have broken file with all information in one column.
- **`File header names should be the same as field names in database.`** This is required by Magento Admin, so in case you have ‘Product Title” column instead of ‘Name’ needed, you have to rename it, since it might not be recognized in the process of Magento import.
  Please, pay attention that some of database fields names have underscore and some don’t. For instance: _attribute_set VS sku.
- Your import file should be saved with correct coding format in order for the data to be correctly recognized. **`UTF-8 Without BOM`** can be set in any spreadsheet program you are using to open files.

**Update:** Make sure the column names do not start with an underscore in your import file.

An example would be the type column – which should be “**`type`**” not “**`_type`**”.

Same for other column headers in the import file, make sure they do not start with an underscore

Please let me know if the problem still persists.

Comment: in website column having value "base" is correct or not

Comment: still i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

There maybe some reasons to this issue, in my case, I formated my CSV file to solve this issue (source https://magentoexplorer.com/fix-error-magento-skipping-import-row-required-field-sku-is-not-defined-when-importing-product)

**CSV file not in UTF8 format**

Open a CSV editor such as Excel and change your file's format to Unicode UTF8, Magento supports this type of file

**Only 1 product in 1 Line**

Check if your CSV file contains more than 1 products per line,

**Missing required fields**

Check if your file contains all of these required fields

type_id or _type –

```
_attribute_set

tax_class_id 

weight 

sku 

name 

price 

description 

short_description
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem, you should first export customer from the Magento (to which you are going to import), then open that file and check the first row, and then compare it with the heading of your CSV.

I was importing CSV file, but the first letter of the website was capital in CSV and Magento was unable to recognize it.

I just export the customer.csv file from Magento, to which I was importing and then compare both, the CSV which I was importing consist of heading like Name, Email, Website, I just change it to name, email, website and it worked for me.

after that, Magento give me an error that website with name "Main website" doesn't exist, I then again change it to base, because the exported file contain website with name of base, and it worked for me.